# EFCORE 2.2.6 Simple join throws Must be a reducible node

Tags: ef-core-2.2

I'm upgrading an application to EF 2.2, but using EFCore 2.2.6 keeps throwing "Must be a reducible node" ArgumentException when I try to do a simple join.

like

```
var list = (from a in db.TableA().Include("TableC")
       join b in inMemoryList on a.Id equals b.AId
       select a).ToList();
```

If I change to

```
var list = (from a in db.TableA().ToList()
       join b in inMemoryList on a.Id equals b.AId
       select a).ToList();
```

It works, but slow down the process.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This happens from time to time between EF Core versions.

In general, avoid joins to in-memory collections if you can - they've never been supported well.

Use `Contains` for single field filtering where possible, for instance

```
var ids = inMemoryList.Select(x => x.AId); // has to be outside the query expression tree
var list = db.TableA.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: The constains work, but now when I add an include statment, it broke again. :(

Comment: `Include` generally does not break the `Contains` concept. If you have a concrete issue, consider asking a separate question and provide [mcve].